# Overwrite a function in a function

Tags: javascript, extend

I am trying to figure out how to extend :

```
var outdatedBrowser = function(options) {
  function startStylesAndEvents() {
   console.log("bleh");
  }
}
```

I am trying to overwrite the function startStylesAndEvents without touching the source code of the library : https://github.com/burocratik/outdated-browser/blob/develop/outdatedbrowser/outdatedbrowser.js

So when I call:

```
outdatedBrowser({
    bgColor: '#f25648',
    color: '#ffffff',
    lowerThan: 'transform',
    languagePath: 'your_path/outdatedbrowser/lang/en.html'
})
```

and it uses the startStylesAndEvents function, it uses mine instead of theirs...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without modifying the original source? You can't.

All of JavaScript scoping is based on functions (ignoring `let`, `const` and `class` for the moment). If a value is declared inside of a function, it cannot be accessed outside of that function unless it is returned from the function or modifies some external value.

For example, imagine a function like this:

```
function doStuff() {
  var times = 10;
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    doThing(i);
  }
}
```

Your question is semantically identical to asking how to change `times`. It just can't be done.

Answer (score 2):

The inner function is contained within a closure, which you don't have access to.  Unfortunately (contrary to the "nothing is impossible" ideology) this can't be done at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

That is what you might call a 'private' function. The function is stored just like any other variable. In JavaScript that generally means it has to be 'local scope' (instead of a member variable) so it cannot be overridden. (if only they had used `this.functionName`... then you could override more easily)

The good news is, there is a hack which seems to be cross-browser compatible. (tested in IE 11, with emulation options back to IE 5!) In JavaScript, you can replace the actual 'source code' of the function itself. (a bit different than a proper override)

```
var newInnerFunction = function () { // intentionally anonymous for use in eval
}
var overriddenFunction = eval(
    outdatedBrowser.toString() // expecting outdatedBrowser to be anonymous for use in eval
    .replace('{', '{var startStylesAndEvents=' + newInnerFunction.toString() + ';')
)
```

Note that `outdatedBrowser` is an anonymous function (simply `function()`). If it were named, then the use of `eval` would have the side effect of adding the new function to the namespace under its original name. An additional `replace` could take care of that if it were an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you can't. But it's not completely impossible.

For example, if you call `startStylesAndEvents` inside a `with` statement whose scope object has been leaked to the outside

```
var scope = Object.create(null);
var outdatedBrowser = function(options) {
  function startStylesAndEvents() {
     console.log("bleh");
  }
  with(scope) {
    startStylesAndEvents(); // You expect this to be the private function above
  }
}
outdatedBrowser(); // "bleh"
```

Then, you can hijack calls to `startStylesAndEvents`:

```
scope.startStylesAndEvents = function() {
  console.log("blah");
};
outdatedBrowser(); // "blah"
```

Don't do this, of course. It's evil, slow and not allowed in strict mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires "touching the source code of the library" which is not going to work for the OP.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Not necessarily. The question doesn't say how the library calls the function. If the library calls that function inside a `with` statement whose scope object has been leaked to the outside, you don't need to modify the library. Highly improbable, but not impossible.

Comment: I think OP is avoiding changing `outdatedBrowser`.

Comment: @MikeC I'm not saying OP should change `outdatedBrowser`. OP has clearly skipped some code (otherwise there is no point in altering `startStylesAndEvents` because it's not called inside `outdatedBrowser`). I'm just saying that if that call was inside a `with` statement, then you can hijack `startStylesAndEvents` without altering `outdatedBrowser`.

Comment: @Oriol They have skipped some code to avoid posting everything here. [It's called inside of `outdatedBrowser`.](https://github.com/burocratik/outdated-browser/blob/develop/outdatedbrowser/outdatedbrowser.js#L120)

Comment: OK, then the improbable condition does not hold, but it could have worked if the library was different.

Comment: It would be incredibly coincidentally convenient if the source code in question was designed this way...